# Docker build error when RUN aws <command> Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

My docker file needs to connect to aws codeartifact to add a source to Nuget before the rest of the image can be built. As of now everytime the build gets to:
`RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --domain mydomain --domain-owner $account_id --repository myrepo` the docker build fails and prints the error: **Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://codeartifact.us-east2.amazonaws.com/v1/authorization-token?domain=mydomain&domain-owner=<account_id>"**.

The first part of my DockerFile is this:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli:latest

ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
ARG AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
RUN echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
RUN echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
RUN echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
RUN echo $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 

WORKDIR /app


RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --domain mydomain --domain-owner <account_id> --repository myrepo
```

I pass the build args in through the command line too. I also run `docker build with --network=host --build-args etc.`.

Nothing is working. I greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!!

Comment: I'd recommend running this command outside a container before you run `docker build`.  Anything you pass into an image build as an `ARG` will be persisted into the image and can be extracted later; that is, this approach compromises your AWS credentials.

Comment: Agreed just testing. How would I run it outside and pass the value into the container during the build process?

Comment: Why can't it connect?  What error does it give?  Is it networking or permissions?

Comment: I've turned off my file wall and ensured that connections aren't being blocked by my machine. The error that docker gives me is: `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://codeartifact.us-east2.amazonaws.com/v1/authorization-token?domain=mydomain&domain-owner=<account_id>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct endpoint for code artefact is

```
codeartifact.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/codeartifact.html

and the error shows `codeartifact.us-east2.amazonaws.com`

So seems like the region arg/env is not correct and it `-` is missingin the region variable.

Try something

```
ENV="us-east-2"
RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --domain mydomain --domain-owner <account_id> --repository myrepo
```